# When UIButton is toggled Map View isn't filing the whole screen iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am new to using MapView in iOS, here's my situation:
When I toggle the nearby button it will redirect me to map view:

[image] 
Then when I toggle the List View button, it will display a UItableView with a Map Button. Then finally, when I toggle the map button it will display the Map View.
My problem is, when in list view then I scrolled down then toggle the map view button the map view doesn't fill the whole screen (please see image for reference):

[image]
Here's what i have so far:
This is how i initiate the Map:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
jobsMapView = [[MTJobsMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,    self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
jobsMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
jobsMapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
jobsMapView.rotateEnabled = NO;
jobsMapView.parentViewController = self;
jobsMapView.delegate = jobsMapView;

// Set up buttons but hide them
showListViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
showListViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-58, self.view.frame.size.height-159, 50.0, 36.0);
[showListViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleNearbyView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[showListViewButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:showListViewButton];

showMapViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
showMapViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-58, self.view.frame.size.height-159, 50.0, 36.0);
[showMapViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleNearbyView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[showMapViewButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_map.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:showMapViewButton];

// Default mapView is shown in Nearby View
showListViewButton.hidden = YES;
showListViewButton.enabled = NO;
showMapViewButton.hidden = YES;
showMapViewButton.enabled = NO;
self.listViewSelected = NO;
}

- (IBAction)toggleNearbyView:(UIButton *)sender {
self.listViewSelected = !self.listViewSelected;

if (self.listViewSelected) {

    self.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Nearby Jobs (%d)",[[self.jobsDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] count]];
    // TableView is shown, so showMapViewButton for user to select MapView
    showMapViewButton.hidden = NO;
    showMapViewButton.enabled = YES;
    showListViewButton.hidden = YES;
    showListViewButton.enabled = NO;
    [jobsMapView removeFromSuperview];

} else {
    showListViewButton.hidden = NO;
    showListViewButton.enabled = YES;
    showMapViewButton.hidden = YES;
    showMapViewButton.enabled = NO;
    self.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Nearby Jobs (%d)",[[self.FilterDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] count]];
    [jobsMapView mapViewWithJobsDisplayed:self.FilterDictionary andUserLocation:xapp.self.userLocation andUserCoordinates:xapp.self.userLocationCoordinates];
    [self.jobsTableView addSubview:jobsMapView];
}
}
```

what am doing wrong here?
Any help will be appreciated..
thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Comment This line.

self.listViewSelected = !self.listViewSelected;

in toggleNearbyView method

Comment: if i comment that line, when i toggle list view button it keeps on showing the map view

Comment: first time u add both tableview and map view. so u have to remove mapview [jobsMapView removeFromsuperview] .